# new FontFace() doesn't work in create react app

Tags: javascript, create-react-app, font-face

I wanna make a dynamic font loader

```
import './App.css';

function App() {

  const font = async () => {
    try {
      const font = new FontFace('ko', 'url(ko.ttf)');
      const loadedFont = await font.load();
      console.log(loadedFont);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={font}>Click</button>
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I got an error when I click on the button

```
Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:3001/ko.ttf
OTS parsing error: invalid version tag
DOMException: A network error occurred
```

It's too simple code..
what's wrong and how can i fix it

Comment: why dont you apply font via css direct

Comment: I wanna change font after rendered by user interaction

Comment: where did you keep your font file? is the url correct? try `url("./ko.ttf")`

Comment: Doesn't work either, i think url is correct

Comment: why don't you try adding class rather than changing font. i mean load fonts in css class and just toggle class on click